# Label individual bars in a grouped bar chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a programmatic way to provide axis labels for individual bars in a grouped bar chart in HighCharts?

**Use case:** The use case is when dealing with a graph that is both grouped and stacked. With these graphs it is hard to visually convey (without a tooltip) what the individual bars represent, unless they have individual labels.

**Default behavior:**
As an example see the HC demo for a stacked and grouped column graph, in which it might initially be unclear that the individual bars in each cluster represent different genders: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

**Goal:** Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve. Is it possible to do this programmatically, such as with a second x-axis? Perhaps another idea would be to use clever placement of the stack total, but of course that would get in the way of showing the actual stack total.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options which may help you.

Firstly, the stackLabels formatter allows you to determine what is in you label.

Secondly, veticalAlign:"bottom" allows you to position the labels at the bottom of the stack.

Thirdly, the 'y' option allows you to move the label relative to its default position.

The catch is that you can't seem to move the label outside of the chart plot area. One way round this is to start your y-axis at a negative value to give room for the labels. You can then move the position of the x-axis into the chart area.

http://jsfiddle.net/WY6QB/

```
xAxis: {
            offset:-43,
            labels:{
                y:40
            },
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },


stackLabels: {
                verticalAlign:"bottom",
                y:20,
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return  this.stack;
                }
            }
```

The only thing left is to try to remove the spurious '-2' y axis point.

-EDIT-
If you set startOnTick to false, and give the y-axis min as -1.9, the spurious -2 point goes away.

```
min: -1.9,
startOnTick:false,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V6Cp2/

Comment: Very cool workaround. This is perfect so long as the normal stack label (i.e. the numeric total of the bars) is not needed. Can you think of a way to adapt this for situations in which you need both the numeric stack label (at the top) in addition to the stack title below?

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to start annotating the chart using the render directly to add text where you want. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the same result as your image, but it displays the `stackLabels`:

```
yAxis: {
    ...
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return  this.stack;
        }
    }
},
```

It displays the label at the top of the column.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CSyLV/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grouping categories](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories) plugin.